# GCM receiver with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I know this question has been asked multiple times but my requirement is a little different so pls bear with me.

I use two different libraries in my android application. One is for parse push notification which has the following declarations:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.airloyal.ladooo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and the declaration for the other receiver is:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.airloyal.ladooo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I definitely need both the libraries in my app so removing one is not an option. I use both the receivers for different purposes. But when I declare both the receivers there is a conflict and I am not able to receive any push notifications.

Can someone pls point me in the right direction?

P.S Both the libraries are jar files and I do not have control over the receivers of both. So forwarding is not an option.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the broadcast receivers are conflict with each other, you may try to set the `priority` of your receiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml` in `<intent-filter>`

Use this attribute only if you really need to impose a specific order in which the broadcasts are received, or want to force Android to prefer one activity over others.

The value must be an `integer`, such as "100". `Higher numbers have a higher priority.` The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.

sample code:

```
<intent-filter android:icon="drawable resource"
               android:label="string resource"
               android:priority="integer" >
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

Also, another way to solve, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397163/gcm-and-parse-notification-conflict).